# AngluarJS promise not exiting cleanly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httprequest

I have a very simple promise, it executes, I get the return response, and while processing the return response its like the function never exits.  My testing has gotten more and more simple just getting it down to the basics and yet the problem persists - can't for the life of me see why its doing this.

```
isError = 0 ;
// validating corporate ID
if ($scope.installType == 1) {
  $scope.errMsg = "Validating Corporate Business ID" ;
  document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.textDecoration = 'blink' ;

  return apiService.all()
  .then(function(response){
    var corpData = response[0] ;
    if (corpData.rowCount == 1 && corpData.data[0].corpID == $scope.userObj.corp_ID) {
      // theoretically a match was found
      console.log("no error") ;
    } else {
      // no match was found
      console.log("with error") ;
      isError++ ;
    }
    console.log("isError: "+isError) ;  // this prints to console
    //return ;  // had added this thinking it was stuck inside the promise, still didn't work
  }) ;
  console.log("hereA") ;  // <-- never gets here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That log does not execute because it is placed after a return statement.

```
isError = 0 ;
// validating corporate ID
if ($scope.installType == 1) {
  $scope.errMsg = "Validating Corporate Business ID" ;
  document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.textDecoration = 'blink' ;

  return apiService.all() // <= watch this return statement
      .then(function(response){
        var corpData = response[0] ;
          if (corpData.rowCount == 1 && corpData.data[0].corpID == $scope.userObj.corp_ID) {
          // theoretically a match was found
           console.log("no error") ;
        } else {
           // no match was found
          console.log("with error") ;
          isError++ ;
        }
        console.log("isError: "+isError) ;  // this prints to console
        //return ;  // had added this thinking it was stuck inside the promise, still didn't work
      }) ;
  console.log("hereA") ;  // <-- Code after a return never executes
}
```

Put it anywhere else before that `return` and it will execute as it should. I have re-indented your code a bit and commented it, hopefully it's easier to understand.

To avoid having this sort of headaches in the future consider installing something like [Eslint](http://eslint.org/) and integrate it in your IDE/editor. [Its no-unreachable rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unreachable) would have warned you straight away of the problem you were facing.

EDIT:

```
if ($scope.installType == 1) {
  $scope.errMsg = "Validating Corporate Business ID" ;
  document.getElementById('errorMsg').style.textDecoration = 'blink' ;

   apiService.all() // <= removed return statement
      .then(function(response){
        var corpData = response[0] ;
          if (corpData.rowCount == 1 && corpData.data[0].corpID == $scope.userObj.corp_ID) {
          // theoretically a match was found
           console.log("no error") ;
        } else {
           // no match was found
          console.log("with error") ;
          isError++ ;
        }
        console.log("isError: "+isError) ;  // this prints to console
        //return ;  // had added this thinking it was stuck inside the promise, still didn't work
      }) ;
  console.log("hereA") ;  // <-- this executes
}
```

Comment: the only return in that promise chain had been commented out.  It should have just exited back into the original `if ($scope.installType...)`.  With or without the `return`, the outcome is the same...it never makes it to `hereA` - which means the bigger function the entire above code is a part of never gets executed.

Comment: No, the return you have commented out is inside the `then` and does not change the fact that `console.log('hereA')` never executes, they belong to different contexts. Try executing the code I update now, it will log `hereA`

Comment: ah...I follow you.  I wasn't even thinking of that return, my focus was further down.  Testing now.

Answer (score 2):

IT never get's there because the console log is outside of the function chain you have built, and it occurs after a return.

Comment: well, that I figured.  But why isn't it the chain returning at all?  I had added added a `return ;` after the console.log("isError: "+isError) but that wasn't working either.  I figured without a `return` it would just complete the chain and exit normally...when that didn't work, then I added the return to force it and that is not working either.

Comment: I would say most likely that the call is erroring. You only have a success function, so in the case of an error nothing will seem to happen.

Comment: the call is fine...thats what the `no error` and `with error` is doing - the fact that either one prints to console means that the promise is not erroring out.

Comment: that is actually not what they are doing if you are using angular $http or $resource.  The .then only goes through if your HTTP call went through successfully. Otherwise, the second call provided is called.

Example:  users.get().then(success, error);

Comment: You were saying the samething as the other guy but I wasn't understand the problem...once I realized I was looking at the wrong `return` I was able to get things working with his rewrite.  Thanks.